# Django: Receiving data from dynamic form value field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

Working on converting an app from Flask to Django and getting stuck on how I can pull data from the value of a form button.  I have some data that is rendered in a table with a for loop.  Each entry has a button displayed that allows my to flip an integer field for the rendered data.  Once it's flipped, it's no longer listed.

```
# manage.html
{% for ticket in tickets %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ my_obj.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ my_obj.tt }}</td>
        <td>{{ my_obj.user }}</td>
        <td>{{ my_obj.time }}</td>
        <td><form action="/flip/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="flip" value="{{ my_obj.id }}"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Kill"/>
            </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}    


# views.py
def flip(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    tt_id = request.POST.get('value')
    return HttpResponse(tt_id )

def manage(request):
    my_obj = MyObject.objects.filter(status=1)
    return render(request, 'manage.html', {'my_obj': my_obj})
```

Currently I am getting a response of None rather than the actual ID which is showing in the value field with firebug.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the fields by the name, not with `value`. e.g.

```
request.POST.get('flip')
```

If you want to access the buttons value, you need to set the name attribute on it.

For details on your request it is helpful for print or return the whole `request` object. A debugger would be an other way to take a look at it.